# UI Automator Viewer's GUI Broken

Tags: android, swt, ui-automation, android-uiautomator, uiautomatorviewer

### The problem

The whole GUI is broken. No messages, no texts in the buttons, weird symbols, etc.
I think it might be the SWT [(see image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gM7fi.jpg).

### Environment

- Desktop OS: macOS Catalina 10.15.4 (19E287)
- Mobile platform/version under test: Android
- Real device or emulator/simulator: Emulated device via Android Studio QEMU
- Java: 
  Installed Java with brew.

  > openjdk version "1.8.0_252"
  >   OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_252-b09)
  >   OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 25.252-b09, mixed mode)
- Android Studio
  Installed from official webpage.

  > Android Studio 4.0
  >   Build #AI-193.6911.18.40.6514223, built on May 20, 2020
  >   Runtime version: 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593 x86_64
  >   VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
  >   macOS 10.15.4
  >   GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
  >   Memory: 1237M
  >   Cores: 12
  >   Registry: ide.new.welcome.screen.force=true
  >   Non-Bundled Plugins:

### Steps to reproduce

1. Install Java 8
2. Install Android Studio
3. Install Intel HAXM
4. Run from terminal `uiautomatorviewer` or `/Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/uiautomatorviewer`

### Enviroment variables

```
export JAVA_HOME_8=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)

export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME_8
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin

export M2_HOME=/opt/apache-maven-3.6.3
export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin

export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/user/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/build-tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
```

Maybe I'm missing something. Also, if logs are needed please tell me.
Thanks

Comment: Apple recently ditched 32-bit support, which might be the cause. So far the OS version is the only relevant information; try running it from the console in order to eventually get more output. Sadly I can't tell how to list the libraries a binary is linked against, but there might be such command, too.

Comment: I'm running it from the terminal. I searched for a verbose output, a debug mode and for a log file but found nothing. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using dark mode, can you try switching your macOS theme to light mode? I got a Java update dialog which looked similar to your screenshot. I realized the texts were there but they were white and couldn't be seen over a white window background. I realized this when I clicked on a button.

[image: Java update dialog]

Answer (score 1):

You must change to Light mode appearance in your Mac setting

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I was able to fix it by switching from adoptopenjdk to using Java 1.8.0_231. Could be that the problem is the different GUI they use in adoptopenjdk vs oracle. From adoptopenjdk FAQ "For JDK8, AdoptOpenJDK is using an open-source renderer called Pisces. " Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

MAC solution:

The only way to make this tool uiautomatorviewer work was by following [this Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ulQ67E2zTE8), where you have to go to this [Eclipse website](https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/index.html), and download the release `4.20` (newer releases didn't work). Once you click on the `4.20` release, scroll all the way to the bottom to the section `SWT Binary and Source` and download the one compatible with your mac (mine was  swt-4.20-cocoa-macosx-x86_64.zip).
Open the zip folder and rename the file `swt.jar` to `swt2.jar`.
Next, go to your /tools/bin folder
Open the folders x86 and x86_64 and paste that `swt2.jar` file inside.
Restart your Terminal and try to open `uiautomatorviewer` again.

NOTE: when you open it the first time, the minimize, maximize buttons will work, but you wont see the buttons to capture a screenshot. Just click maximize and minimize and that will make them show up.

Answer (score 0):

Broken UiAutomator GUI

1. uiautomatorviewer comes built-in with Android SDK - /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/android-sdk/tools/bin/uiautomatorviewer
2. Execute in that directory using ./uiautomator (If needed use sudo for permission)
3. If the UI opens but broken, go to https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/index.html and download(4.20 or 4.19 works) -> Under "SWT Binary and Source" download  for your platform (For mac M1, swt-4.19-cocoa-macosx-x86_64.zip)
4. Extract the zip file and rename swt.jar to swt2.jar
5. Paste swt2.jar file in x86 and x86_64 directories.
   /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/android-sdk/tools/lib/x86
   /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/android-sdk/tools/lib/x86_64
6. Now open terminal, go to /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/android-sdk/tools/bin/ and run uiautomatorviewer
   $ sudo ./uiautomatorviewer

Answer (score 0):

For me, on my Mac, once the `uiautomatorviewer` window opened, the toolbar which has icons to take screenshot/capture UI hierarchy was not showing. After resizing the windows, the toolbar starts showing. Go figure...